# How to check if hard disk is encrypted or not using VC++?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, wmi

I need to check if hard disk is encrypted or not. Do windows provide any API to do the same. Can this be achieved using WMI? Any info or link would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, you can use WMI. Specifically, this method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376448.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if a drive is encrypted using the [`Win32_EncryptableVolume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376483.aspx) WMI class and checking the value of the `ProtectionStatus` property, from here  you can wrote a WQL sentence like so :

`SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume Where DriveLetter='C:'`

Note : This WMI class requires admin rights.

Try this sample code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

//CREDENTIAL structure
//http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374788%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
#define CRED_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH            513
#define CRED_MAX_CREDENTIAL_BLOB_SIZE       512
#define CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH CRED_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH
#define CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH (CRED_MAX_CREDENTIAL_BLOB_SIZE / 2)


#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    wchar_t pszName[CREDUI_MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH + 1] = L"user";
    wchar_t pszPwd[CREDUI_MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH + 1] = L"password";
    BSTR strNetworkResource;
    //To use a WMI remote connection set localconn to false and configure the values of the pszName, pszPwd and the name of the remote machine in strNetworkResource
    bool localconn = true;
    strNetworkResource = localconn ? L"\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption" : L"\\\\remote--machine\\root\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption";

    COAUTHIDENTITY *userAcct = NULL;
    COAUTHIDENTITY authIdent;

    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    HRESULT hres;
    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    if (localconn)
        hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
            NULL,
            -1,                          // COM authentication
            NULL,                        // Authentication services
            NULL,                        // Reserved
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation
            NULL,                        // Authentication info
            EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities
            NULL                         // Reserved
            );
    else
        hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
            NULL,
            -1,                          // COM authentication
            NULL,                        // Authentication services
            NULL,                        // Reserved
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY,    // Default Impersonation
            NULL,                        // Authentication info
            EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities
            NULL                         // Reserved
            );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;
    hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *)&pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object." << " Err code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    if (localconn)
        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
            _bstr_t(strNetworkResource),      // Object path of WMI namespace
            NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
            NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
            0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
            NULL,                    // Security flags.
            0,                       // Authority (e.g. Kerberos)
            0,                       // Context object
            &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
            );
    else
        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
            _bstr_t(strNetworkResource),  // Object path of WMI namespace
            _bstr_t(pszName),             // User name
            _bstr_t(pszPwd),              // User password
            NULL,                // Locale
            NULL,                // Security flags
            NULL,                // Authority
            NULL,                // Context object
            &pSvc                // IWbemServices proxy
            );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to root\\CIMV2\\Security\\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption WMI namespace" << endl;

    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------
    if (localconn)
        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
            pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
            RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
            RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
            NULL,                        // Server principal name
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
            NULL,                        // client identity
            EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities
            );
    else
    {
        // Create COAUTHIDENTITY that can be used for setting security on proxy
        memset(&authIdent, 0, sizeof(COAUTHIDENTITY));
        authIdent.PasswordLength = wcslen(pszPwd);
        authIdent.Password = (USHORT*)pszPwd;
        authIdent.User = (USHORT*)pszName;
        authIdent.UserLength = wcslen(pszName);
        authIdent.Domain = 0;
        authIdent.DomainLength = 0;
        authIdent.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_UNICODE;
        userAcct = &authIdent;

        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
            pSvc,                           // Indicates the proxy to set
            RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
            RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
            COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
            userAcct,                       // client identity
            EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities
            );
    }

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(L"WQL", L"SELECT * FROM Win32_EncryptableVolume Where DriveLetter='C:' ",
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "ExecQuery failed" << " Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
        cin.get();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Secure the enumerator proxy
    if (!localconn)
    {

        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
            pEnumerator,                    // Indicates the proxy to set
            RPC_C_AUTHN_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
            RPC_C_AUTHZ_DEFAULT,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
            COLE_DEFAULT_PRINCIPAL,         // Server principal name
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,  // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,    // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
            userAcct,                       // client identity
            EOAC_NONE                       // proxy capabilities
            );

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            cout << "Could not set proxy blanket on enumerator. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
            cout << _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << endl;
            pEnumerator->Release();
            pSvc->Release();
            pLoc->Release();
            CoUninitialize();
            cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
            cin.get();
            return 1;               // Program has failed.
        }
    }

    // Get the data from the WQL sentence
    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if (0 == uReturn || FAILED(hr))
            break;

        VARIANT vtProp;

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"DeviceID", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);// String
        if (!FAILED(hr))
        {
            if ((vtProp.vt == VT_NULL) || (vtProp.vt == VT_EMPTY))
                wcout << "DeviceID : " << ((vtProp.vt == VT_NULL) ? "NULL" : "EMPTY") << endl;
            else
                wcout << "DeviceID : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ProtectionStatus", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);// Uint32
        if (!FAILED(hr))
        {
            if ((vtProp.vt == VT_NULL) || (vtProp.vt == VT_EMPTY))
                wcout << "ProtectionStatus : " << ((vtProp.vt == VT_NULL) ? "NULL" : "EMPTY") << endl;
            else
                wcout << "ProtectionStatus : " << vtProp.uintVal << endl;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtProp);


        pclsObj->Release();
        pclsObj = NULL;
    }

    // Cleanup

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    if (pclsObj != NULL)
        pclsObj->Release();

    CoUninitialize();
    cout << "press enter to exit" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.
}
```

Comment: Whether the above code give the information of disk encryption if we encrypt it by using 3rd party vendor software.